# Converting XML data to CSV powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

Hello I am new to Powershell but I have looked all over for an answer to this question, how do I convert XML data to CSV data in power shell.

My XML data looks like this:

```
<SolarWinds_SwitchPortMap Layer2Device="<info>">
     <Interfaces>
           <Interface ifIndex="<data>" CollectionTime="<data>" ConnectorPresent="<data>" Duplex="<data>" HardwareType="<data>" ifAdminStatus="<data>" ifAdminStatustest="<data>" ifAlias="<data>" ifDescr="<data>" MACAddress="<data>" MTU="<data>" ifName="<data>" ifOperStatus="<data>" ifSpeed="<data>" ifType="<data>" ifTypeName="<data>" InBitsSec="<data>" InPktsSec="<data>" LastChange="<data>" LastPacketIn="<data>" LastPacketOut="<data>" ModulePortIndex="<data>" OutBitsSec="<data>" OutPktSec="<data>" Port="<data>" TrunkPort="<data>" />
     </Interfaces>
</Solarwinds_SwitchPortMap>
```

I can't seem to get Powershell to understand the xml data,

```
set-location "<program location>"
.\swspmcmd.exe <info> /xml > "<output_location>\output_data.txt"
get-content "<output location>\output_data.txt" | select -skip 17 | set-content "<xmldata_location>\xmldata.xml"
$xml = [xml] (Get-Content "<xmldata_location>\xmldata.xml")

$xml | convertto-csv -Delimiter:"," -NoTypeInformation
```

And it will only return
"SolarWinds_SwitchPortMap"
"System.Xml.XmlElement"

and I don't understand why, any help is greatly appreciated thanks :).

Comment: You can't convert XML to CSV like that due to the fundamentally different structure (hierarchical vs. tabular), so you need to "manually" extract the information you need from the XML and prepare them for CSV export. What do you want the CSV to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're after the data in the interfaces node you could do something like this:

```
[xml]$a = @"
<SolarWinds_SwitchPortMap
    Layer2Device="info">
     <Interfaces>
           <Interface 
           ifIndex="data" 
           CollectionTime="data" 
           ConnectorPresent="data" 
           Duplex="data" 
           HardwareType="data" 
           ifAdminStatus="data" 
           ifAdminStatustest="data" 
           ifAlias="data" 
           ifDescr="data" 
           MACAddress="data" 
           MTU="data" 
           ifName="data" 
           ifOperStatus="data" 
           ifSpeed="data" 
           ifType="data" 
           ifTypeName="data" 
           InBitsSec="data" 
           InPktsSec="data" 
           LastChange="data" 
           LastPacketIn="data" 
           LastPacketOut="data" 
           ModulePortIndex="data" 
           OutBitsSec="data" 
           OutPktSec="data" 
           Port="data" 
           TrunkPort="data"
           />
     </Interfaces>
</SolarWinds_SwitchPortMap>
"@

$a | select-xml  -xpath "/SolarWinds_SwitchPortMap/Interfaces/Interface" | select -ExpandProperty Node | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path ./interface.csv
```

Comment: Thank-you the, -ExpandProperty Node, did it :)

Comment: Nice, this helped me out with my own conversion problem